# Can't create asp.net membership database aspnetdb

Tags: asp.net, mdf, aspnetdb, wsat

I can't seem to create the aspnetdb.mdf via the Web Site Administration Tool.
I am using SQL Express 2008 and Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express.
I get following error in the Administration Tool:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: An error
>   occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The
>   SQL error number is 5170 and the SqlException message is: Cannot
>   create file 'C:\USERS**\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2010\WEBSITES\BUGZ-B-GONE\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF' because it
>   already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
>   operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
>   created. Check related errors. Creating the
>   ASPNETDB_97c73957a1fb4a189ccca0449aa7d754 database...

I also get this error when I delete the mdf file or change the path.

Underneath is the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   <add name="DATABASEConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
   <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
          name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that the database is already present, so first delete it and then run WSAT. If not works then delete your web.config and add a new config file to your project and then run WSAT and add the aspnetdb database.

Also you can try [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Run it, then you can add or remove AspNet database tables from your database.
Read more detail on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)